# Trigger in linked server doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

I'm trying insert the same values from one table in my server1 to the server2. I have two server, one of them with Windows Server 2012 and SQL 2012 and the other with Windows Server 2003 and SQL 2005, in my server1 (Server 2012) I created a database name "test" with one table named "usuario" and in the server2 (Server 2003) I created a database named "test" with one table named "user" with the follow columns: id,name,lastname,email,phone and marital status; in the server2 I have the same database with the same values.

So I decided, first, created the link server one server to other and it's all ok but if I want insert the same values in both servers my trigger didn't work. I configure in both servers: the firewall windows ports 1433 and 135 to TCP/IP and UDP connection, the SQL client network tool, the SQL Services and Distributed Transaction Coordinator Service are running and configure in Windows Service Components to enable and accept Transaction without authentication and the properties from linked servers it's ok in both servers. All looks like ok but when I insert something the consult take more than 5 minutes and remains processing.

Someone can help me? Another detail it's when I consult from one server to other the query bring me the result and it's all ok, no matter the server. My trigger looks like:

```
USE [test]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[insertUser] ON  [test].[dbo].[user] AFTER INSERT AS 

DECLARE @id int

DECLARE @name varchar(50)

DECLARE @lastname varchar(50)

DECLARE @email varchar(50)

DECLARE @phone int

DECLARE @maritalstatus varchar(50)

SELECT @id=i.id FROM inserted i;

SELECT @name=i.id FROM inserted i;

SELECT @lastname=i.id FROM inserted i;

SELECT @mail=i.id FROM inserted i;

SELECT @phone=i.id FROM inserted i;

SELECT @maritalstatus=i.id FROM inserted i;

INSERT [192.168.11.128].[test].[dbo].[user] SELECT * FROM inserted
GO
```

And my insert looks like:

```
USE [test]

GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[user]([id],[name],[lastname],[email],[phone],[maritalstatus])VALUES(1503,'paul','armstrong','something@something',505301,'engaged')

GO
```

I don't know if I do something wrong. Another comment, I do the same trigger but with two server both witth Windows Server 2003 and SQL 2005 and in this case the insert and the trigger it's successfull. Could it be that the SQL version has something to do with compatibility?

Comment: Triggers in sql server are fired per statement, not per row his means that if you ever try to insert more than one row into the table your trigger will raise an error - "subquery returned more then one value".

Comment: @ZoharPeled Are you sure you will get that error? It will actually assign the value of the "last" row in inserted to each of those scalar variables. And I don't see a subquery in there at all. But yes the scalar variables are a huge red flag...and in the code here they are completely pointless as nothing is done with them.

Comment: @ZoharPeled can you explain me what's the correct form to execute that trigger?

Comment: @SeanLange you are correct. It will only throw an error if the syntax is `SET @variable = (SELECT column FROM Inserted)`

Comment: @CamiloPacheco As I wrote in my comment, triggers are fired per statement, this means that there can be 0, 1 or more records in the inserted and deleted tables. Your trigger code should always handle the inserted and deleted tables as if they have multiple rows in them.

Comment: @ZoharPeled but I don't understand why this same trigger function with the 2 sever with SQL 2005 and Windows Server 2003, in fact, I use it only change the linked server name and the insert it's succesfull in this case, do you thing that, maybe, the version of SQL have something to do?

Comment: Well, If I had known the reason I would try post an answer... :-)

Comment: So the issue is that this works but it takes too long? Have you isolated what part is going slow? I am a bit confused as to what you are asking.

Comment: @SeanLange yes, take too long and after 2 minutes, more or less,a message appears:

Comment: The instruction is finished.
Mens 7202, Level 11, State 2, Procedure InsertEvent2, Line 22
The 'LINK12' server can not be found in sysservers. Run sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sysservers.

Comment: ding ding....it isn't that it takes too long it is that it fails. And now we have an error message. Of course the error message is not consistent with the code you provided. But the message is extremely clear. You are trying to reference a remote server using a linked server named LINK12 and it doesn't exist as a linked server. The error message is extremely clear on this one.

Comment: But the linked server named LINK12 it's already add as Linked Server in Object Explorer. I do a test connection and it's ok